# How to awk -f everything after the last \

Tags: windows, awk, cmd, grep

I have this where it could be one \ or multiple

```
C:\folder\file.log
C:\folder\folder\file.log
C:\folder\folder\folder\file.log
```

I want to get this

```
file.log
```

This works but its static with print $.

```
cat C:\folder\file.log | awk -F "\\" "{print $3}"
cat C:\folder\folder\file.log | awk -F "\\" "{print $4}
cat C:\folder\folder\folder\file.log | awk -F "\\" "{print $5}
```

How can i awk and always grab the data after the last \

Comment: Is it important that you use awk? While it is fairly easy, there are tools built into Windows (cf.: Powershell) that have methods bulit into them for exactly this job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the $NF special variable, which gives you the number of fields in your input.

```
echo C:\folder\file.log | awk -F "\\" "{print $NF}"
```

Comment: Presumably you want `echo` not `cat`. `cat` puts the file through `awk`, not the file name,

Comment: Thanks, that worked

`FOR /F "delims=" %%i in ('echo %BUGReportFile% ^| awk -F "\\" "{print $NF}"') do set BUGReportFile=%%i`

Answer (score 2):

with grep:

```
grep -o '[^\\]*$' file
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have awk, do you also have "basename"?

and as pointed out above, windows has similar capabilities built in.